# Implementing Chain of Responsibility with LinkedList

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list, chain-of-responsibility

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this, and I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have a Chain of Responsibility class, and I'm wondering if I can (and would want to) implement it as a derivative of the LinkedList class. At its core, a Chain of Responsibility is, of course, a linked list, but I'm not sure if deriving from LinkedList is really appropriate here, since each implemented method needs to be able to call the same method in the successor if the current one fails.

Can you implement something like `public class MyHandler : LinkedList<MyHandler>`? That seems like a recursive definition, but the compiler doesn't consider it a problem.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Oh, I should add that I've googled and nothing I found implements a CoR as a LinkedList derivative, which suggests to me that either you can't, or it's not a good idea.

Comment: Interesting question - can you give a little more detail or an example of the how the CoR would work?  Not necessarily the code, but the process.

Comment: The idea was to have handlers added in sequence to a linked list, then call the top one in the chain, and if it fails it automatically calls the same method in the next handler in the chain (e.g., MyHandler.Successor, which is also a MyHandler). I thought LinkedList was pretty much designed for this and had already implemented a lot of the methods (AddFirst, AddLast, Next, etc.) that I'd want to add to my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can inherit from `LinkedList`, just like you can inherit from any non-[sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.  However, I don't think it's a good idea.  Inheritance is not just fo re-using methods.  It conveys an ["is a" relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Although the chain of responsibility pattern can certainly be implemented using a linked list, a chain of responsibility *is not* a linked list.

When deriving from the `LinkedList` class, you'll be exposing *all* its public methods.  You should also ask if all those methods make sens for your class.  I don't think the [`LinkedList.Average()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549067%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) makes any sens to a chain of responsibility.

You should instead store the handlers in a linked list which is a private data member of your chain of responsibility implementation.

> Can you implement something like public class MyHandler : LinkedList? That seems like a recursive definition, but the compiler doesn't consider it a problem.

Yes, this is perfectly legal.  It is a recursive definition and can come in handy when implementing the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), for instance.  This would

I would advise against writing the class that way for the same reasons your chain of responsibility shouldn't inherit from `LinkedList`, but this is possible.

Comment: You have a good point about .Average, but then again, one of the examples I see listed in several places is of a LinkedList<string>, where .Average would also be inapplicable.

Comment: Why would it not be inapplicable?  You can compute the average string length.  You can also store numbers in their string representation and compute the average by converting the numbers to decimal.

Comment: Anyways, it's just an example.  If you look at the interface, there a loads of methods that don't make sens for a chain of responsibility, including [`GroupBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(VS.95).aspx) and [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).

Comment: While you *could* implement Average as an average string length, that makes an assumption that that's what Average should do in that instance. It's not a pre-defined, obvious thing to assume, though.

In any event, now that I look more closely at .Net's implementation of LinkedList, it's obviously not quite what I was looking for. In essence, I think what I'm looking for is more the equivalent of LinkedListNode, since each method has to have access to the next node in the chain, but that's a sealed class.

Comment: You're right that many of the Extension methods don't apply, though all the basic methods of LinkedList are desirable, as well as some of the Extension methods (e.g., Where). I'll rethink what I'm doing and see what makes sense.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: I'm thinking of writing a generic class to implement most of the functionality of LinkedList that I'm interested in, but leave out what makes no sense. Is there a better declaration than `public abstract class ChainOfResponsibility<T> where T : ChainOfResponsibility<T>` for this kind of recursive definition given that I want to implement this as strongly-typed rather than untyped? (Obviously, I'll implement IEnumerable, etc., as well, but keeping it simple for now.)

Comment: If the class in question is supposed to be for handlers in the chain, I would suggesting finding a better name (e.g., one that's reflects the fact that each item is not the chain, but a link/node in the chain).  Also, `class CoR<T> where T : CoR<T>` will obviously fail, as that's a recursive template parameter definition.  Also, why are you insisting on use of inheritance?  It seems to me your best bet here is composition.  `class CoR<T>{ CoR<T> head; CoR<T> tail; T data; }` seems to me much easier to write, and much, much easier to read.

Comment: The chain doesn't really exist as an object in its own right...the first object *is* the chain, for all intents. I'm using inheritance because it's what I know, and it makes sense to me that the various types of handlers would be derivatives of a base class. I have no idea what the class definition you wrote above is...I've never seen that style of declaration before - my knowledge of OOP is a little out of date. I'll Google it.

Also, CoR<T> where T : CoR<T> compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: @AndréCaron let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2140/discussion-between-robinhood70-and-andre-caron)